# Issue with Google Tag Manager not listening to dataLayer.push

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

So we are working to implement Enhanced ECommerce tracking for a client. We have done this with a dataLayer push. The web developer has implemented our code as suggested but there have been instances when the dataLayer.push is missed for a few transactions.

I have attached the code below for how it is currently implemented on the Order success page.

There could be some issue with AngularJS implemented on the website and would be grateful if someone can help me to understand how I should implement the GTM code for those missed page views and dataLayer.push codes.

When I am viewing in GTM debug window, there are two instances that happen;

1. The purchase event will trigger in the dataLayer.push and we get the transaction data in Google Analytics.
2. The page-view will trigger and no dataLayer.push event will follow. Even though when I check the page source the dataLayer.push codes are available for purchase.

   function getCartproducts() {

   ```
       var dataLayerIndex = new Array();
           dataLayerIndex.push({"name": "xxxxxx" , "id" :  "xxxxxx" , "price" :  "11.00" , "category" :  "xxxxx" , "quantity" : 2});

       return (JSON.stringify(dataLayerIndex));
   }

   function getCoupon(){
       var couponLayerIndex = new Array();
           couponLayerIndex.push('');

       return (JSON.stringify(couponLayerIndex[0]));
   }



   window.dataLayer.push({
       'event': 'checkout',
       'ecommerce': {
           'checkout': {
               'actionField': { 'step': 5 },
               'products':
                 JSON.parse(getCartproducts())
           }
       },
   })



   window.dataLayer.push({
       'event': 'purchase',
       'ecommerce': {
           'purchase': {
               'actionField': {
                   'id': '269459',
                   'revenue': 25.65,
                   'tax': '3.85',
                   'shipping':'7.50',
                   'coupon': getCoupon(),
           },
               'products': JSON.parse(getCartproducts())
   }
   }
   });
   ```

I expect the code to trigger a custom purchase event every time the final thank you page is viewed by a user. But as described, we miss quite a number of transactions.